# Узнать URL до загрузки страницы C# WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Добрый день. Возникла следующая задачка: приложение на selenium должно узнавать url загружаемой страницы до ее загрузки, проверять, соответствует ли он нужному, и если да, то менять текст в DOM. Что-то вроде:

```
if(Страница изменена) {
    //?Остановить загрузку страницы
    if(Текущий урл == "Нужный урл") {
         //Изменить нужный элемент
         //Продолжить загрузку страницы
    } else
         //Продолжить загрузку страницы
}
```

Сложность возникла при попытке остановить страницу при загрузке, важно, чтобы страница не загружалась полностью, то есть чтобы UI не успевал появиться.
Из идей было создать отдельный поток, который выполняется раз в определенное кол-во миллисекунд, и проверяет, соответствует ли урл нужному, но проблема в том, что поток узнает урл только после полной загрузки страницы.

Comment: А как инициируется открытие страницы? Если по сслыке, то у нее есть атрибут href, который как раз и есть url будущей страницы (если редиректов на нем нет).

Comment: Нет, страницы инициализируются непосредственно пользователем в браузере. То есть в коде заранее не известно, какая страница будет открыта.

Comment: Тогда только JS скриптом, наверно.. Попробуйте задать вопрос у JS-ников